# How to Add keys to python dicitonary dynamically?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying to creating python dictionary keys dynamically in order to serve the data into csv file but not getting anywhere so far. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

class ZiwiScraper:

    results = []
    
    headers = {
    'authority': '99petshops.com.au',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-language': 'en,ru;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'cookie': 'TrackerGuid=f5419f8d-632a-46b1-aa04-eed027d03e89; _ga=GA1.3.1385392550.1666770065; _gid=GA1.3.1560927430.1666770065',
    'referer': 'https://www.upwork.com/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Yandex";v="22"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.114 YaBrowser/22.9.1.1110 (beta) Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
}

    def fetch(self, url):
        print(f'HTTP GET request to URL: {url}', end='')
        res = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
        print(f' | Status Code: {res.status_code}')

        return res
    
    def parse(self, html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        titles = [title.text.strip() for title in soup.find_all('h2')]
        low_prices = [low_price.text.split(' ')[-1] for low_price in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'hilighted'})]
        store_names = []
        stores = soup.find_all('p')
        for store in stores:
            store_name = store.find('img')
            if store_name:
                store_names.append(store_name['alt'])
        shipping_prices = [shipping.text.strip() for shipping in soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'shipping'})]
        price_per_hundered_kg = [unit_per_kg.text.strip() for unit_per_kg in soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'unit-price'})]
        other_details = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'pd-details'})
        
        for index in range(0, len(titles)):
            try:
                price_per_100_kg = price_per_hundered_kg[index]
            except:
                price_per_100_kg = ''
            try:
                lowest_prices = low_prices[index]
            except:
                lowest_prices = ''
            for detail in other_details:
                detail_1 = [pr.text.strip() for pr in detail.find_all('span', {'class': 'sp-price'})]
                for idx, price in enumerate(detail_1):
                    self.results.append({
                        'title': titles[index],
                        'lowest_prices': lowest_prices,
                        f'lowest_price_{idx}':  detail_1[idx],
                        'store_names': store_names[index],
                        'shipping_prices': shipping_prices[index],
                        'price_per_100_kg': price_per_100_kg,
                    })
                    
#         json_object = json.dumps(self.results, indent=4)
#         with open("ziwi_pets_2.json", "w") as outfile:
#             outfile.write(json_object)
            
    def to_csv(self):
        with open('ziwi_pets_2.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=self.results[0].keys())
            writer.writeheader()

            for row in self.results:
                writer.writerow(row)

            print('Stored results to "ziwi_pets_2.csv"')
            
    def run(self):
        for page in range(1):
            url = f'https://99petshops.com.au/Search?brandName=Ziwi%20Peak&animalCode=DOG&storeId=89%2F&page={page}'

            response = self.fetch(url)
        
            self.parse(response.text)
        
        self.to_csv()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = ZiwiScraper()
    scraper.run()
```

Every time I run the script it gives me the above code I got `ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'lowest_price_1'`. csv file however generating with one entry only.

```
title,lowest_prices,lowest_price_0,store_names,shipping_prices,price_per_100_kg
Ziwi Peak Dog Air-Dried Free Range Chicken Recipe 1Kg,$57.75,$64.60,Woofers World,+$9.95 shipping,$5.78 per 100g
```

I tried to output it as json just to see the data formation and it was also not as I expected.

```
[
    {
        "title": "Ziwi Peak Dog Air-Dried Free Range Chicken Recipe 1Kg",
        "lowest_prices": "$57.75",
        "lowest_price_0": "$64.60",
        "store_names": "Woofers World",
        "shipping_prices": "+$9.95 shipping",
        "price_per_100_kg": "$5.78 per 100g"
    },
    {
        "title": "Ziwi Peak Dog Air-Dried Free Range Chicken Recipe 1Kg",
        "lowest_prices": "$57.75",
        "lowest_price_1": "$64.60",
        "store_names": "Woofers World",
        "shipping_prices": "+$9.95 shipping",
        "price_per_100_kg": "$5.78 per 100g"
    },
    {
        "title": "Ziwi Peak Dog Air-Dried Free Range Chicken Recipe 1Kg",
        "lowest_prices": "$57.75",
        "lowest_price_2": "$64.95",
        "store_names": "Woofers World",
        "shipping_prices": "+$9.95 shipping",
        "price_per_100_kg": "$5.78 per 100g"
    },
]
```

I expected something like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Ziwi Peak Dog Air-Dried Free Range Chicken Recipe 1Kg",
        "lowest_prices": "$57.75",
        "lowest_price_0": "$64.60",
        "lowest_price_1": "$64.60",
        "lowest_price_2": "$64.95",
        "store_names": "Woofers World",
        "shipping_prices": "+$9.95 shipping",
        "price_per_100_kg": "$5.78 per 100g"
    },
]
```

Can anyone please help me out here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass as `fieldnames` *all* the keys any item in `self.results` might have. The error should go away if you just add that into your `to_csv` function

```py
def to_csv(self):  
        fNames = list(set([k for r in self.results for k in r.keys()]))
        fNames.sort(key=lambda r: (
            -1*(int(r.replace('lowest_price_', ''))+1) if 'lowest_price_' in r else 0, r
        ), reverse=True)

        with open('ziwi_pets_2.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fNames)
            writer.writeheader()

            for row in self.results:
                writer.writerow(row)

            print('Stored results to "ziwi_pets_2.csv"')
```

(The `sort` statement is optional - it's just to make sure the columns are in a certain order.)

---

As for this bit

> I expected something like this

the `for idx, price in enumerate(detail_1)` in the `parse` function is appending a new line *for every lowest_price_idx value* of each `detail`. To get get them all in one line, change the outer loop to

```py
            for detail in other_details:
                result_i = {
                        'title': titles[index],
                        'lowest_prices': lowest_prices,
                        'store_names': store_names[index],
                        'shipping_prices': shipping_prices[index],
                        'price_per_100_kg': price_per_100_kg,
                    }

                detail_1 = [pr.text.strip() for pr in detail.find_all('span', {'class': 'sp-price'})]
                for idx, price in enumerate(detail_1):
                    result_i[f'lowest_price_{idx}'] = detail_1[idx] 

                self.results.append(result_i)
```

Then, your csv output will go from
[image: csv before editing loop]
to
[image: csv after editing loop]

and you json would look, as expected

```json
{
    "title": "Ziwi Peak Dog Air-Dried Free Range Chicken Recipe 1Kg",
    "lowest_prices": "$57.75",
    "store_names": "Woofers World",
    "shipping_prices": "+$9.95 shipping",
    "price_per_100_kg": "$5.78 per 100g",
    "lowest_price_0": "$3.87",
    "lowest_price_1": "$4.49",
    "lowest_price_2": "$5.09",
    "lowest_price_3": "$5.95",
    "lowest_price_4": "$5.99"
}
```

(printed using `print(json.dumps([r for r in scraper.results if len(r) == 10][0], indent=4))`)

Answer (score 0):

You were creating csv header based only upon the first result, which didn't contained whole set of unique keys.

Change to_csv function to this to resolve your problem:

```
def to_csv(self):
    key_list = list()
    for key_list_for_one_element in [list(x.keys()) for x in self.results]:
          key_list.extend(key_list_for_one_element)
    key_list = set(key_list)
    with open('ziwi_pets_2.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=key_list)
        writer.writeheader()

        for row in self.results:
            writer.writerow(row)

        print('Stored results to "ziwi_pets_2.csv"')
```

Comment: It worked but not as I expected. For example: as you can see in the csv https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c_LmEmORhS-E66zBuKFmi72txIU-Zb32dIQhGF5zKH4/edit?usp=sharing generated from your code snippet it is including all the entries but title and other fields are duplicating and I'd like to have only one title row per entry. Something like this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tuDgx53XA7s4I0ByBnFELVCaS-EKRvPLNUB4G2Vz1JU/edit?usp=sharing it is a different dataset but only to reference.

Comment: In parser function you can change this line:
**f'lowest_price_{idx}':  detail_1[idx],**
into this:
**f'lowest_price':  detail_1[idx],**

That way you will not have multiple 'lowest_price' columns with a different postfix

Comment: Which line you are referring to?